# How to extract particular strings from a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have scanned for a list of Bluetooth devices which looks like:-

```
[{'address': '00:0C:99:88:77:66', 'name': 'FK20020', 'rssi': -49, 'packet_data': {'connectable_advertisement_packet': {'flags': bytearray(b'\x06'), 'complete_list_16-bit_service_class_uuids': bytearray(b'\t\x18\x02\x18'), 'complete_local_name': 'FK20020'}, 'scan_response_packet': {}}}, {'address': '77:11:22:33:44:55', 'name': 'PQR11225', 'rssi': -49, 'packet_data': {'connectable_advertisement_packet': {'flags': bytearray(b'\x06'), 'incomplete_list_128-bit_service_class_uuids': bytearray(b'\x07\xb9\xf9\xd7P\xa4 \x89w@\xcb\xfd,\xc1\x80H'), 'complete_local_name': 'PQR11225'}, 'scan_response_packet': {}}}, {'address': '77:55:33:22:44:99', 'name': 'PQR05286', 'rssi': -49, 'packet_data': {'connectable_advertisement_packet': {'flags': bytearray(b'\x06'), 'incomplete_list_128-bit_service_class_uuids': bytearray(b'\x08\xc9\xf9\xd9P\xa4 \x89w@\xcb\xdd,\xc3\x90H'), 'complete_local_name': 'PQR05286'}, 'scan_response_packet': {}}}]
```

From the list, i only want devices whose name starts with "PQR" (for example PQR11225 or PQR05286), and form a list which contains their 'name','address' and 'rssi'

Is there is way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a list comp:

```
got=[(i['name'],i['address'],i['rssi']) for i in devices if i['name'].startswith('PQR')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the list, and only pick out names that start with `PQR`

```
result = []
for device in devices:
    if device['name'].startswith('PQR'):
        result.append(device)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comp approach-

```
[(i['name'], i['address'], i['rssi']) for i in bluetooth_list if i['name'].startswith('PQR')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `filter` for this as

```
res = []


for dev in list_:
    if dev['name'].startswith('PQR'):
            tmp = {'name':dev['name'],'address':dev['address'], 'rssi':dev['rssi']}
            res.append(tmp)

print(res)
```

output

```
[{'name': 'PQR11225', 'address': '77:11:22:33:44:55', 'rssi': -49}, {'name': 'PQR05286', 'address': '77:55:33:22:44:99', 'rssi': -49}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter your list base on the device name:

```
list(filter(lambda s: s['name'].startswith('PQR'), my_list))
```

output:

```
[{'address': '77:11:22:33:44:55',
  'name': 'PQR11225',
  'rssi': -49,
  'packet_data': {'connectable_advertisement_packet': {'flags': bytearray(b'\x06'),
    'incomplete_list_128-bit_service_class_uuids': bytearray(b'\x07\xb9\xf9\xd7P\xa4 \x89w@\xcb\xfd,\xc1\x80H'),
    'complete_local_name': 'PQR11225'},
   'scan_response_packet': {}}},
 {'address': '77:55:33:22:44:99',
  'name': 'PQR05286',
  'rssi': -49,
  'packet_data': {'connectable_advertisement_packet': {'flags': bytearray(b'\x06'),
    'incomplete_list_128-bit_service_class_uuids': bytearray(b'\x08\xc9\xf9\xd9P\xa4 \x89w@\xcb\xdd,\xc3\x90H'),
    'complete_local_name': 'PQR05286'},
   'scan_response_packet': {}}}]
```